# Angular Provider/Factories/Directives like $mdDiaog

Tags: angularjs, factories

Angular allows you to use `$mdDialog` or `<md-dialog>` and I want to mimic this in my own application. Like I want to create a service or something that allows you to set a value on it. For example,

`shareSheet.show({
  items: [twitter, facebook, email],
  title: "Share Action",
})`

and then depending on a few config things I want that to either show a bottom sheet or a FAB menu. So what should I be using to do this? i looked at how `$mdDialog` and `$mdBottomSheet` were implemented and it is really confusing. Any help is awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$mdDialog` is a service. It has many functions one of which is the show function. The show function gets an Object based on which it places or adds a directive in the page implicitly. That directive creates the dialog.

So to mimic this behavior create a directive and service. The service should get data and add the directive to the page.

Comment: How does something implicitly add a directive?

Comment: I meant using javascript you should add the directive to the page. So that it will be displayed in the view. Or you can show a hidden directive using ng-if.